# From where exactly does the airport bus near Schottentor U2 in Vienna leave?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, vienna, vie

My app and this [site](https://www.flughafenbus.wien/en) insists there is an airport bus going from Schottentor/Liechtensteinstrasse to the airport. I have been at Schottentor many times. I am unable to find either bus or Liechtensteinstrasse. I am severely disabled and cannot walk very far, so I would appreciate very precise instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The zoomable map at https://www.viennaairportlines.at/en/stops shows Liechtensteinstraße and the airport bus stop, 3-4 blocks from the tram terminal at Schottentor. The "stop info" says

> Vienna Airport Lines buses stop on Liechtensteinstraße (by the Liechtensteinstraße exit from Schottentor underground station, on the U2 line).

which suggests that there is a separate eastern exit from the U-Bahn station.

The map at https://www.wien.gv.at/stadtplan/en/grafik.aspx?lang=en&bookmark=jildRsI0NEZJg6NErTsURO5RphlRnKnmkev2pn4Mpr4C appears to show the route of the airport bus as a green line. It agrees with the above map about the location, but on the other hand shows U2 one street over from where it looks like it is on Google Maps (and the few street photos I can find), so caveat lector.

*(I have no personal experience with this location, but it grew too long for a comment).*

Comment: In fact, the U2-symbol on the map just shows that there is a station there. The entrances and exits can be recognized by "U-Bahn Zugang" (sic!). The main entrance(s) is(are) at the intersection of Universitäts-(Schotten-)ring with Währinger Straße/Schottengasse, but there is (are) another one (two) in Liechtensteinstraße, so the map is not wrong in fact but maybe just unfortunately designed. Note however, that the exit to Liechtensteinstraße doesn't have an elevator (there is an escalator though), the elevator leads to the main entrances at the intersection.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: Ah, that clears it up. I hadn't zoomed far enough in for the "U-Bahn Zugang" notations to show up -- and for some reason the one in Hohenstaufengasse/Liechtensteinstraße only shows up at the largest zoom level, whereas the main entrances show up earlier than that.

Comment: Note that the airport bus line stopping at Schottentor doesn't operate anymore, so you have to go to some other underground station now to take the bus to the airport. (as of December 4, 2017 (see at https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=viennaairportlines+schottentor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8))